# How to retrieve multiple fields with form in HtmlService?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the situation : I have a form created by HtmlService, and several items have the same names because I want to retrieve them in a array.

Here is an example:

```
 <html>
  <form method="post" action="address of my published script (or dev address for the test)" > 
    <input type="text" name="field" />
    <input type="text" name="field" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
</html>
```

(Ok, it seems useless here, but it'll be interesting when user can add fields of the same name dynamically, so I won't know how many they are).

In the function `doPost(e)`, I wish to have `e.parameter.field` equals to `[value1, value2]`. Unfortunately, I only have the first element.

I read that in PHP we can write `name="field[]"`, but it doesn't work either.

Do you know any solution for doing that ?

Thanks for your answers ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.parameters (note the s at the end) will have precisely what you want.